# App's one of two Documents Folder not Saving on Windows

Tags: windows, ipad, ios4, xcode4.2, itunes

I have a application in which there are two folders in app's document directory.
a. Thumbnail.
b. Recordings.

Contents of Recordings Directory: Recordings in .caf format, and naming of those records are like "Recording#[number]"+[datetime].
Few examples of names of the recorded file:

```
2012-04-26 06/11/50 +0000.caf
2012-04-26 06/11/37 +0000.caf
```

So the problem is, when i Sync my iPad on MAC using itunes, i can save both the folders, which are Thumbnails and Recordings. But when i Sync on Windows, Recordings folder doesn't save. Thumbnail folder is saved with no problem, but when i save Recordings folder, it doesn't appear, means it is not saving at all.

I tried one remedy, which is, change the names of the recorded files like: Recording1.caf
If i save my recorded files with such naming convention, Then the Recordings Folder is saving on Windows with no problem.

One more thing i like to mention here, when using recording names with datetime appended, sync on MAC, send it to windows, files play with quicktime with no problem. (It was very obvious, but didnt want to miss anything.)

What i wanted to ask here, why is it not saving on windows when names are with datetime. Is thats the problem, cant it be solved without changing the name. Because the previous users of this app have their recordings saved with datetime, i'll have to change all those names first when the user updates to the new build.